# How to access most frequently used programs in OS and most recent files of programs programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I need to gain access to the list of most recently used programs and list of recently opened files in Windows OS programatically. These are the items you generally see once you click start in windows. I am looking to use C# but if its better in Managed C++ I will do that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for files you can access recent directory.

```
string folderName =  Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent);
DirectoryInfo recentFolder=new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
FileInfo[] files=recentFolder.GetFiles();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to do the same thing using C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing for Windows 7, then you can use Windows 7 SDK and you can use Managed C++.